# How to run a program on the target machine through an SSH connection?

Tags: windows, winapi, ssh, terminal

So I installed OpenSSH on two of my windows computers. Now I can run commands on one computer through the other. For simple console apps, it works, and I get the output of the program in my ssh terminal. For applications that make windows, it doesn't work. My plan was to be able to run a graphical program from a remote machine and have the graphics show up on the target machine. I've seen some stuff online where the graphical interface is relayed back through the ssh connection, but just to clarify, that's not what I want. I just want to run the software on the computer and have the software run in its normal context on the target machine, as if there were never an SSH connection in the first place.

I don't quite understand why this isn't working. To make a window, you have to use some winapi functions to initialize the window within the system and whatnot, so is SSH blocking those winapi calls and/or the windows messages being sent around the system by those api calls?

Comment: *For applications that make windows, it doesn't work* - what is not work ? process not started ?

Comment: ssh per se does not support graphical information from windows, though there are a lot of options use ssh tunnel to run other protocols like RDP or VNC/RFB

Comment: you can get x windows data though, https://kb.iu.edu/d/bdnt

Comment: @IłyaBursov You must of misunderstood me, I mean to say that I want the graphical interface to run on the target computer, and not be forwarded through ssh. For some reason, ssh blocks this from happening.

Comment: @RbMm The process might be starting, but the graphical interface for the program never shows up on the target machine.

Comment: may be it started in session 0

Comment: @RbMm Sorry, I don't know what you mean by session 0. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa, I don't think your problem is the SSH connection (the protocol) but how the OpenSSH server works on Windows.

I wouldn't be surprised if the OpenSSH server implementation on Windows is only able to give you a shell for command-line-only application (no GUI).

This thread might be helpful:
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/998

Comment: @Mau Thanks, but I still don't quite understand why it doesn't work. I don't think it's a case of OpenSSH not implementing it, because there's nothing to implement. A windows forms application is just a command-line application that sends some windows messages to the system to initialize a window, which then just gets displayed. The computer on which I am trying to start the program already has the desktop open and is signed in, so the window should just pop up.

Comment: @Mau Continuation: I guess there might be some security features in place to block windows messages and just run the code on a different "level", but why would that be the case? SSH is secure and why wouldn't you want to be able to fully use the target computer?

Comment: Somehow, others managed to ask this question at a site where it isn't off-topic. See [Applications executed using SSH don't show on remote machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1297211/applications-executed-using-ssh-dont-show-on-remote-machine).

Comment: @JacksonTarisa , the link provided by IInspectable is really what you need (as an explanation about why it's not working as you expect). Also take a look at the link I sent you: in that forum they cover the same topics ("session 0" and all) but claim that a different SSH server implementation might work. I agree that this question should be posted on SuperUser.

Comment: @Mau Thanks I get it now, and yes the session 0 stuff was in the forum post as well, but maybe I skimmed to quickly and didn't realize what it fully entailed, srry about that. In regards to the SuperUser stuff, at the time of posting this question I don't believe I knew that that forum existed. I'm not saying I'm not to blame, I definitely could have looked it up first and found SuperUser on my own. Regardless, I'll pay more attention to where I post things in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.